# permission denied while posting the form which contains textarea with html content

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmyadmin

Ok, so here's my problem (which I've googled and no help):

I have a form which has the textarea element, and in it I want to write something like:

```
<table><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>
```

and click submit and i want it to be saved in database.

Now, my code is working if I enter nonHTML characters, but if I enter as above I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /xxx/sample_posteddata.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My guess is that somehow my hosting has some security enbaled to disallow this?

I've tried to insert the exact text from the php admin interface and that works fine :?

**EDIT:** full source code of the file podaciEdit.php:

```
<?
            require_once("_dal/CredentialsManager.php");
            require_once("_dal/ProizvodRepository.php");
            $repos = new ProizvodRepository();

            if ( isset( $_POST["spremi"] ) ){
                $sifra = $_POST["sifra"];
                $naziv = $_POST["naziv"];                        
                $slika = $_POST["slika"];                   
                $podaci_full = htmlspecialchars($_POST["podaci_full"]);

                $podaci_min = $_POST["podaci_min"];
                $kategorija = $_POST["kategorija"];
                $kategorija_naziv = $_POST["kategorija_naziv"];

                if ($repos->updateProizvod ($sifra, $naziv, $slika, $podaci_full, $podaci_min, $kategorija, $kategorija_naziv))
                    echo "Podaci uspješno spremljeni!";
                else{
                    echo "Greška prilikom spremanja podataka!";                                             
                }

                echo '<br/>Kliknite <a href="proizvodiEdit.php">ovdje</a> za povratak.';
            }
            else if ( isset( $_GET["sifra"] ) ){
                $sifra = $_GET["sifra"];
                $proizvod = $repos->GetProizvod($sifra);

                if ($proizvod){                        
                    $sifra = $proizvod["sifra"];
                    $naziv = $proizvod["naziv"];                        
                    $slika = $proizvod["slika"];                        
                    $podaci_full = $proizvod["podaci_full"];

                    $podaci_min = $proizvod["podaci_min"];
                    $kategorija = $proizvod["kategorija"];
                    $kategorija_naziv = $proizvod["kategorija_naziv"];



                    //$data = htmlentities($podaci_full, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
                    echo <<<qq
                    <form id="proizvodEdit" method="POST" action="proizvodEdit.php">

                                            Podaci - tablica: (mozes resizeati po potrebi!)<br/>
                    <textarea class="podaci_full" id="podaci_full" name="podaci_full">{$podaci_full}</textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Spremi sve" name="spremi"/>
                    </form>

qq;
                }
                else
                    echo '<h2 class="title-page">Proizvod koji tražite ne postoji.</h2>';

            }
            else{
                echo '<h2 class="title-page">Proizvod koji tražite ne postoji.</h2>';
            }
```

Comment: Without code, we can only guess.

Comment: are you trying cross-domain post?
use strip_tags() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @Rob W: please see now, I've c/ped the whole php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the thing that helped resolve the issue was function [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

```
$podaci_full = stripslashes($_POST["podaci_full"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the website you can use `htmlspecialchars()` then save the output to the database. If you want to read it back and convert to html use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

*for a more accurate answer, you should post the code you use to save the data to the database.*

Comment: as you can see i use the htmlspecialchars() but to no help :(

Comment: @Nikola Does this method `updateProizvod()` do any further processing on the data ?

Comment: public function updateProizvod($sifra, $naziv, $slika, $podaci_full, $podaci_min, $kategorija, $kategorija_naziv){
   if ($this->openConnection()){
                $sql = "UPDATE proizvodi SET sifra='$sifra', naziv='$naziv', slika='$slika', podaci_full='$podaci_full', podaci_min='$podaci_min', kategorija='$kategorija', kategorija_naziv='$kategorija_naziv' WHERE sifra='" . $sifra . "'";                
    echo $sifra;
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
                if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1)
     return true;
    else
     return false;     
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
  }

Comment: @Nikola You are not escaping your data properly (to prevent SQL injections use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the parameters before using the in the `update` query).

Comment: yes, i know that and thank you but this does not produce an error, i get an error even if i comment out the whole database saving part

Comment: @Nikola Sorry but I'm out of ideas, I'll upvote your question hoping someone with better skills may help you.

Comment: thank you. I hope I get this fixed, as I'm out of options too :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got a 403 initially. This is an file permissions related issue, an apache error message, not a php one. Try to go directly to www.yourdomain.com//xxx/sample_posteddata.php and see if you can access the file. Maybe even try a GET param.

```
www.yourdomain.com//xxx/sample_posteddata.php?sifra=xxx
```

You should be able to access it. If not [try](http://www.lost-in-code.com/server-management/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/)

```
chmod +x /home/domain/public_html
```

404 is the error code for NOT FOUND. It means that your form is not pointing correctly to your php file or one of the includes fails. Check your paths.

Comment: the code is working perfectly if I enter normal text (no HTML tags) in the text area and click Submit. It also gets saved to db just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since your HTML is containing the keyword "table", my best bet would be that it is probably an issue related to mod_security or some other security tool which filters SQL keywords, in order to help prevent SQL injections. Try adding the below to your `.htaccess`:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
```

If it works this way, it's probably about mod_security. Note that you may not be able to disable it from your `.htaccess` file though.